# PHP Memory Limit Increased 2 times, Still Causing Issue

Tags: php, memory, server

My server is running out of PHP memory within a day time.

Originally it was set to 128mb it ran out causing my website to go blank, then i increased to 198mb and again it has ran out, now increased to 512mb.

Can you some one guide me why this issue is recurring again and again, how i can fix this issue.

Help highly appreciated

Comment: we can read your mind ... check current process

Comment: which server are you using ?

Comment: The question is why do you run out of memory? What do you do so memory consuming?

Comment: Fix the disease not the symptom

Comment: as @NullPoiиteя said - you have to check all processes, where is the bug, as this cause memory leaks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you must find memory leaks in your application. You can do this with **xdebug profiler** or **xhprof**. Then you will see what is causes this problem. Until that time it's hard to give any advice.